# Dropdown list box as EditTemplate in DataGrid - not binding

Tags: html, asp.net

I do not know who to bind the dropdownlist used in the edit template of a grid view. The error I get is "Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Type'." Here is an excerpt from the grid view...

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type *" SortExpression="Type">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceType" DataTextField="Code" DataValueField="LookupValuesID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Code") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorddlTypeEdit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Type is required" ControlToValidate="ddlTypeEdit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcegrvLeases" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MFPConnectionString1 %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[LeaseAgrmntID], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[SalesOrderID], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[SerialNo], [tlkp_Lookup_Values].[Code], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ContractNo], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ScheduleNo], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[StartDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Term], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Hours], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Rate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ReturnDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[CloseDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ExtensionStartDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ExtensionTerm] FROM [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt] LEFT JOIN [tlkp_Lookup_Values] ON [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Type] = [tlkp_Lookup_Values].[LookupValuesID] WHERE ([SalesOrderID] = @SalesOrderID) ORDER BY [LeaseAgrmntID]" 
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt] SET [SalesOrderID] = @SalesOrderID, [SerialNo] = @SerialNo, [Type] = @Type, [ContractNo] = @ContractNo, [ScheduleNo] = @ScheduleNo, [StartDate] = @StartDate, [Term] = @Term, [Hours] = @Hours, [Rate] = @Rate, [ReturnDate] = @ReturnDate, [CloseDate] = @CloseDate, [ExtensionStartDate] = @ExtensionStartDate, [ExtensionTerm] = @ExtensionTerm WHERE [LeaseAgrmntID] = @LeaseAgrmntID">
    <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlLeaseSalesOrder" Name="SalesOrderID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="SalesOrderID" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="SerialNo" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="ContractNo" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="ScheduleNo" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Term" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Hours" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Rate" Type="Decimal" />
         <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ReturnDate" />
         <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="CloseDate" />
         <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ExtensionStartDate" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="ExtensionTerm" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="LeaseAgrmntID" Type="Int32" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting this error because your select query does not include the type field. If you modify your query to follow I think it will work just fine. Notice the addition of **[tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Type]** just before the `FROM` keyword.

```
SELECT [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[LeaseAgrmntID], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[SalesOrderID], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[SerialNo], [tlkp_Lookup_Values].[Code], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ContractNo], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ScheduleNo], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[StartDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Term], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Hours], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Rate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ReturnDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[CloseDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ExtensionStartDate], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[ExtensionTerm], [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Type] FROM [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt] LEFT JOIN [tlkp_Lookup_Values] ON [tbl_Lease_Agrmnt].[Type] = [tlkp_Lookup_Values].[LookupValuesID] WHERE ([SalesOrderID] = @SalesOrderID) ORDER BY [LeaseAgrmntID]
```

Comment: When I add the field I get the following error...'ddlTypeEdit' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: What if you change SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Code") %>' to SelectedValue="Code" ?